# Why Brahmins are supposed to offer Sandhya everyday?

Tags: rituals, brahmins

When a Brahmin boy is 8 years old, he has to go through the **Upanayana Samskara** and after that he has to wear the **Janeva** (sacred thread in Marathi) and he is informed to offer Sandhya every day to Sun.

Why Brahmins are supposed to offer Sandhya everyday?

Comment: What is the purpose of this question? Why should a child be sent to school? Why should they be fed nutritious food? Why is it necessary to take medicine when one is sick? Questioning everything about Hinduism and brahmanas has become a fashion it seems. They do it because they are supposed to. Why are they supposed to? "Because shaastra says so" is a good enough answer.

Comment: There may be reasons that can be provided but this questioning every single aspect of the religion, and responding to such questioning will have long term negative consequences on dharma where anything that is unexplainable using modern thought frameworks (which are limited) shall be deemed unnecessary. We are actually seeing this happening these days.

Comment: @moonstar2001 my friend i am also brahmin but to make it clear to all i asked this question

Comment: it is 'garbhashtam' - 8 years since conception or 7 years after birth, not 8 years since birth.

Comment: my point is nothing needs to be made clear. people should just follow.

Comment: It's not restricted to Bramhanas, all the dwijas can perform sandhyavandanam as long as they have Yagnopavita. Dwija varnas are first three varnas viz Bramhana, Kshatriya, and Vaishya.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Having rinsed, the mouth, as laid down in the Mantram, one should
> again rinse it. Then sprinkling one's own self with water, as
> described in the Mantram, one should throw palmfuls of water. (12)
>
> **By virtue of the boon conferred by Brahma, whose birth is not known,
> the Rakshasas Mandeha fight every morning with the Sun. (13)**
>
> **The handfuls of water, thrown by the Brahmanas and inspired with the
> mystic verse Gayatri, destroy all the Rakshasas passing under the
> appellation of Mandeha (14)**
>
> **Harita Smriti, Chapter 6.**

The highlighted portion above gives the "reasons" why a Brahmin should offer water each day to Sun at three Sandhya times (sunrise, noon and sunset).

BTW, Sandhya is a must for all Dvijas i.e compulsory even for any Kshatriya and Vaishya who have gone through the sacred thread ceremony.

And, if a Brahmin fails to do Sandhya then that is an offence and he has atone it by doing penances.

> If a householder, out of mistake, does not perform his
> Sandhya-adoration or deviates from the performance of a Snataka-vow,
> he should fast far the day. (66)
>
> In consequence of willfully [neglecting the Sandhya], the foremost of
> the twice-born should perform the distressing penance [of Prajapatya
> for full one year, and should perform the Chandrayana, [if he does so]
> for livelihood. [And] by making a gift of kine, [he is] purged of [his
> sins]. (67)
>
> **Usana Smriti, Chapter 9.**
>
> He, who out of carelessness fails to perform the Sandhya once, either
> in the morning or in the evening, should, with a concentrated mind,
> recite, after bathing, the Gayatri for a thousand times. (63)
>
> **Atri Smriti**

.........

> This is spoken of as the threefold Sandhya wherein exists the dignity
> of a Brahmana. **He is not called a Brahmana who has no reverence for
> it. (15)**
>
> As serpents cannot approach Garuda, so imperfection cannot approach
> him who fears the non-performance of the Sandhya and who is always
> given to bathing.
>
> **Katyayana Smriti, Chapter 11.**

.............

> Unless badly jeopardised in health, or otherwise incapable, **a
> twice-born one should never neglect the timely performance of his Homa
> and Sandhya rites.**
>
> **Vyasa Smriti's last chapter.**

So, a Dvija should always perform the Sandhya rites without fail.

Comment: that is what i was looking for very clear answer

Comment: Thank you. Its good to know that you have liked it. @sumitamble

Comment: @Rickross Just a question, how many twice-born by birth people do you think do it religiously without fail? Like some percentage?

Comment: I don't know the percentage sorry. Some Brahmins at least should be doing it without fail. @JohnRay

Comment: @Rickross No not exact but just asking - do the majority of Brahmins still do it in Kali Yuga? Seems like people of my age around me are way more influenced by the western culture and extreme liberal ideas.

Comment: Yeah what you say is true but may be 60-70% still does it without fail. @JohnRay