# Sandhyavandanam for those not initiated (without Upanayanam) using Puranas. It is possible?

Tags: puranas, rituals, sandhyavandanam, upanayanam, gayatri

Many statements (eg. ŚB 1.4.25) talk of how non-initiated persons (irrespective of caste) cannot follow Vedic procedures, and how [for them](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16625/are-sudras-not-allowed-to-study-any-scriptures-of-hindusim) to read and follow, the Puranas and itihasas were composed.

A [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48082/does-navagraha-tarpana-in-sandhyavandan-reduce-the-astrological-effects?noredirect=1#comment150765_48082)
on a [post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48082/does-navagraha-tarpana-in-sandhyavandan-reduce-the-astrological-effects) about Navagraha tarpana provides a [manual](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/sandhya.pdf) for 3 types of Sandhyavandanam procedures described in it:

> In this pamphlet we give 3 forms of the Sandhyā the first is that of the Krishna Yajur Veda, the second that of the Sukla Yajur Veda and **the 3rd is a Pauranika version which can be used by any one *without any restriction* whatsoever.**

I’m interested in the Pauranika Sandhyavandanam procedure (given on page 24 of the manual), which contains mantras from the Puranas (not Vedas) except the Gayatri. The procedure is the same. The manual says that this **Pauranika sandhya can be practised by ALL Hindus**, irrespective of social circumstances:

> Learning the Vedic mantras and their correct recitation is time consuming and exceedingly difficult and requires a competent guru, so in order to accommodate those who do not have the aptitude, inclination or the facilities for Vedic study and learning the complex Vedic liturgy and who still wish to live the religious life, the Agamas have prescribed a form of the sandhyā (daily prayer) that **can be self-taught and used by *everyone* regardless of social circumstances.**

**Questions:**

1. As stated in this manual, can the Sandhya as enjoined in the Puranas (using Pauranika mantras) be performed by non-initiates, without a guru giving deeksha of the Pauranika mantra? 
   (Would like scriptural reference, preferably from multiple sources, saying this Pauranika Sandhya can be performed by non intitiates of all castes, men and women both)
2. Since the Gayatri mantra, forms part of the Vedas, can it be used, as instructed in Step 12 of the procedure, while reciting the Pranava and vyahritis too? 
   Also, one can observe that in the Vedic procedure, the Gayatri mantra has Vedic accents. The Pauranika one lacks the accents, the mantra being the same (with the pranava and the vyahritis). In such a case what is the tune/ accent which is to be used while chanting the Gayatri, in case it is allowed?
3. Is the procedure described in the manual exactly endorsed by any of the 18 Puranas? If so which Purāṇa? (See Q4)
4. An [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48085/20129) gives a difference in the procedure described in two Puranas (one including Navagraha tarpana and one excluding). Thus, of *the 18 Puranas*, which one to follow? Is the procedure of the Purāṇa (Q3) which endorses the manual, correct, compared to the one we should follow?

   (Is it dependent on the sect (smarta/ Vaishnava) or God we worship?)
5. The Smritis [enjoin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20307/20129) compulsory Sandhyavandanam for dvijas, failing which a prescribed prāyaścitta must be performed. Is there any rule of compulsion (3 times everyday) for non-initiates (irrespective of caste) and the corresponding prayaścitta?

Comment: Gāyatrījapa is itself niṣiddha for advijas. The manual, you are referring to, isn't from a proper traditional source. The person, who has written that manual, himself rejects śāstrīya vidhāna expounded in smṛtis and related varṇāśrama dharma. Therefore, his words cannot be taken as prāmāṇya and reliable. Gāyatrījapa (without svaras) would still be pāpakarman for anadhikārins of Gāyatrī. Advijas have the option of doing tāntrikīsandhyopāsanā, but that requires dīkṣā in a tāntrikī mūlamantra from a proper guru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 2, if you're not initiated for gayatri, you can chant manas gayatri instead from Ramacharitmanas:

जनकसुता जग जननि जानकी।
अतिसय प्रिय करुनानिधान की॥
ताके जुग पद कमल मनावउँ।
जासु कृपाँ निरमल मति पावउँ॥

janakasutā jaga janani jānakī।
atisaya priya karunānidhāna kī॥
tāke juga pada kamala manāvaum̐।
jāsu kṛpām̐ niramala mati pāvaum̐॥

Comment: Thank you, could you please provide a reference for this being the manas Gayatri? And what about the part that comes thereafter - Puni man krama bachana raghunayaka bandaun charana Kamala  sab layaka?

Comment: Two video references: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlvNbgyLUVo and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgZJan1jCuM

Comment: Thank you @ThomasSatirsley